# Es posible aplicar cambios de visual code usando html en el navegador sin que este se vaya al principìo de la página?

Tags: chrome

lo primero decir que soy novato y acabo de empezar en el mundo de la programación, en concreto en html.
Utilizo visual code y como navegador para el visionado de lo que voy escribiendo el google chrome.
El caso es que instalé la extensión live server para que los cambios que vaya haciendo se apliquen automáticamente y me funciona bien con un pero.
Cuando aplico algún cambio, se actualiza el navegador pero se va al principio de la página siempre. Es decir, lo que intento es que al modificar o escribir alguna linea en visual code, al aplicarlo directamente en el navegador, no se vaya al principio de la página y tenga que estar desplazandome hasta el sitio que he cambiado para ver como queda. Si estoy por ejemplo cambiando un footer, lo que me gustaría es hacer el cambio y teniendo el navegador abierto, en el lugar donde va el footer, vea el cambio sobre la marcha, no que hago el cambio en el visual code, y el chrome lo aplica pero me lleva al principio del todo por lo que tengo que bajar a ver como ha quedado el footer. Espero haberme explicado. Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: ¿Has probado con hacer clic en donde te quieres quedar y recargar la página? A mi me funciona, y utilizo chrome, vscode y live-server como tú...

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar y si pincho en el chrome una vez abierto y toco html en el visual code si sigue ahí. En css no me lo hace, sino que se vuelve al principio del navegador.

Comment: Debería haber alguna opción para que se vaya directamente a lo que vayas tocando en el visual code y ver el cambio "en directo" en el navegador, ya sea html,css o demás.

Comment: "Debería haber alguna opción para que se vaya directamente a lo que vayas tocando" programala ;)... visual studio code es una IDE, con lo cual, no estas programando en eso, lo estas usando para programar, que es muyyyyyyyyy diferente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: De acuerdo, le echo un vistazo, lo del cómo preguntar no lo entiendo y lo de programarlo, jejeje, llevo un par de semanas en el mundillo y parto de cero así que. Un saludo y gracias por contestar.